# Highlight click event with Table that has both row and column spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that is laid out as such:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |   H1    |   H2    |   H3    |   H4    |   H5    |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |          
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
|    S1   |-------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
|    S2   |-------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
|    S3   |-------------------------------------------------+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like help implementing a way of pressing any of the `S1`, `2` or `3` cells (which have a `row span`) that all 'siblings' will be highlighted, much like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|         |XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|
|    S3   |-------------------------------------------------+
|         |XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
    ^
    |
  CLICKED HERE
```

If possible, I would also like to do this with my `H1 -> H5` columns.

I was looking at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianS1987/G2trb/), but am not great with javascript/jquery that I couldn't alter it, only ever being able to 'break' its current functionality.

**WARNING: Long snippet** due to complexity of table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custTitle').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td').css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

```css
.makeInputWidth {
  width: 5em;
}
.rotateText {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  height: 7em;
  width: 6em;
}
.title {
  background-color: #808080;
}
table tr td {
  padding: 0;
}
table tr {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/*  .qwerty{
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thistable">
  <tr>
    <th>LOCATION</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th colspan="2">H1</th>
    <th colspan="3">H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th colspan="2">H4</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S1</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S2</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S3</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S4</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S5</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S6</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S7</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S8</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product id</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="11">&nbsp;</tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Customers</th>
    <th colspan="10">
      <hr />
  </tr>
  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th rowspan="2" class="title">Q1</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="11">
      <hr />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th rowspan="2" class="title">Q2</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="11">
      <hr />
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th rowspan="2" class="title">Q3</th>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" />
    </td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="11">
      <hr />
    </th>
  </tr>





</table>
```

Would anyone:

- **(A)** Understand what I'm talking about, and
- **(B)** Be able to implement this idea?

Here Is a workable [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xgf0mhxL/1/)

**EDIT HISTORY**

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xgf0mhxL/) added
- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xgf0mhxL/1/) updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting rows: You need to select `TR` element that contains the clicked cell, plus next siblings if the cell has a rowspan. You can use [`jQuery.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [`jQuery.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) and [`jQuery.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) together as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".title1").on("click", function() {
    var rowspan = +$(this).attr("rowspan") || 1;
    $(this).closest("tr").nextAll().addBack().slice(0, rowspan).find("th, td").toggleClass("test1");
  });
  $(".title2").on("click", function() {
    var index1 = 0,
      index2 = +$(this).attr("colspan") || 1;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
      var colspan = +$(this).attr("colspan") || 1;
      index1 += colspan;
      index2 += colspan;
    });
    $("tr:gt(2)").find("th, td").filter(function() {
      var index = $(this).index();
      // using heuristic, sorry
      if ($(this).closest("tr").hasClass("custTitle") === false) {
        index += 1;
      }
      return index >= index1 && index < index2;
    }).toggleClass("test2");
  });
});
```

```css
.title1 {
  background-color: #808080;
}
.title2 {
  background-color: #808080;
}
.test1 {
  background: #F99;
}
.test2 {
  background: #99F;
}
.test1.test2 {
  background: #F9F;
}
input {
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="thistable" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>LOCATION</th>
    <th></th>
    <th class="title2" colspan="2">H1</th>
    <th class="title2" colspan="3">H2</th>
    <th class="title2">H3</th>
    <th class="title2" colspan="2">H4</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>PRODUCT</th>
    <th></th>
    <th class="rotateText">S1</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S2</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S3</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S4</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S5</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S6</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S7</th>
    <th class="rotateText">S8</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product id</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th class="title1" rowspan="2">Q1</th>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th class="title1" rowspan="2">Q2</th>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="custTitle">
    <th class="title1" rowspan="2">Q3</th>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="makeInputWidth qwerty" /></td>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <th>TEST</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you Salman A. this seems to do what I was trying to achieve. Now i'm off to learn what you've done so that i can replicate this for the columns!

Comment: Good luck with that; columns will be **much** complicated.

Comment: See revised answer. It turns out that dealing with row and column spans is difficult. A better solution is to use classes to match rows and columns. Even better would be to use `<rowgroup>` and `<col>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#selection td[rowspan]').click(function(e){
    $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    var i = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    for(;i>0;i--){
        $(parent).find('td').addClass('highlight');
        parent = $(parent).next();
    }
});
```

When a click event is triggered on any of the `<td rowspan="2">` tag. The script will first remove any previous highlighting then it will read the value of `rowspan` attribute in this case it is "2". The it will loop 2 times (2 rows, including current row) and highlight all `<td>` tags.

In the loop `parent = $(parent).next();` actually set reference to the next row.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jttd51hs/)**

** **UPDATED** **

I have modified the script a bit to include any rows with no rowspan attribute. (Single row).

```
$('#selection td:first-child').click(function(e){

    var i = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    if(typeof i == 'undefined')
        i=1;
    $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    for(;i>0;i--){
        $(parent).find('td').addClass('highlight');
        parent = $(parent).next();
    }
});
```

Modification: Event triggers changed to `td:first-class` and an if condition is added to check if the current `<td>` tag has any rowspan attribute if not then set value of `i` to 1. (Highlight only current row).

**[FIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jttd51hs/1/)**

Comment: Cheers for the demo/script. In order for me to adapt this for my table/columns, could you possibly describe how/what it's doing?

Comment: Cheers! here is my final [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xgf0mhxL/2/) (BTW, is your jsfiddle cursor messed up presently?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the rowspan of the clicked cell, and apply a css class on every td which belongs to this table row, and the next n (n = rowspan - 1)

```
$('.td_clicked').click(function() {
    var rowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    for (i=1;i<=rowspan:i++) {
       $(this).parent('tr').find('td').addClass('highlighted_cell');
    }
});
```